# Ajax calls within nested divs not working for FireFox with MVC3

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, firefox

I have a cshtml page that has a link, and a div to display some content.

```
<a href="#" onclick="Show_New_Page('#First_Div')>My Link</a>

<div id="First_Div">
    @Html.Partial("General_Page") <- This is the default page that gets displayed on load.
</div>
```

When you click on the link, the javascript function Show_New_Page gets called and the string '#First_Div' gets passed as a parameter.  I pass the name of the div I wish for the ajax in Show_New_Page to put its success value.  That function looks like this:

```
function Show_New_Page(div) {
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: url, //Declared above globally, unimportant
        data: data, //Declared above globally, unimportant
        success: function (result) {
            $(div).html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

When you click on this link in Internet Explorer, the new page gets displayed fine with no issues.  However, when you click on this link in FireFox, the entire page turns white and never successfully loads.

There are plenty of posts about issues with Ajax and different browsers, but I was unable to see one that helped me.  Any hints or tips I can try are much appreciated.  I am very unsure of why this is happening, so if I have left out any information I will certainly do my best to provide it.

Comment: Extra comma after the success callback.

Comment: @BradM shouldn't matter in modern browsers

Comment: No closing parentheses after #First_Div

Comment: @JanDvorak should matter because it's incorrect JSON syntax

Comment: @BradM - Thats correct, there is an extra comma in the ajax and a forgotten paren in my link.  These are editting errors I have made that do not exist in my actual code.  I have edited my corrections.

Comment: @BradM this isn't JSON. This is a Javascript object literal.

Comment: Post your action method?

Comment: @mattytommo - forgive me, what is my action method?

Comment: The method that your AJAX calls.

Comment: Instead of editing your question to include the answer, answer your own question and accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was the fact that my ajax views that were being passed down after clicking on a link were using document.write() statements.  I have learned that this is strange to do after the page has already loaded.  I've moved these statements up to the files that were not being loaded with ajax, and that fixed the problem.  Thank you to everyone who commented and suggested ideas to me.  It was the investigation of these ideas that lead me to the core issue!

**The lesson: be careful with excessive document.write() statements in firefox!**

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a missing closing `)` when you are calling the `Show_New_Page` function. Also it's recommended to return false from click handlers to cancel default action:

```
<a href="#" onclick="Show_New_Page('#First_Div'); return false;">My Link</a>
```

Also you might prefer to give this anchor an id:

```
<a href="#" id="myLink" data-id="#First_Div">My Link</a>
```

and then unobtrusively AJAXify it in a separate file to avoid mixing markup with javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myLink').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url, //Declared above globally, unimportant
            data: data, //Declared above globally, unimportant
            context: { id: $(this).data('id') },
            success: function (result) {
                $(this.id).html(result);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I am trying to implement your suggestions now.

Comment: Your suggestion seems to be a working replacement for what I currently  have, but unfortunately it leaves me in the same state.  The page goes white, and when I run firebug I seem to get an indication in a calendar pop up class that the window object is null.  This makes me think that something prior to this step has made the window object go null, but I am unsure what or why.  I appreciate your response that you have posted.

Comment: Yes it looks like the issue is not related to this code at all. Anyway the replacement I suggested you is an improvement over your initial code. Are there any errors in the FireBug console?

Comment: I have edited my initial question to contain the portion of the firebug console error.  It tries to access the window array, and seemingly ultimately returns null.  The part I do not understand, is that in IE it works fine, just not in firefox.

Comment: I feel I might fail to answer these questions properly, and I thank you for your responses.  This code exists in a file called CalendarPopup.js which is a third party file that can be found here: http://mattkruse.com/javascript/calendarpopup/combined_compact_source.html  This file says that the parseDate function is apart of date.js, but I do not know its origin other than it is included with this calendar pop up.  When the page loads, I instantiate an instance of this calendar for use, and I am guessing that is why this is being called when I navigate to the page via ajax.

Comment: I realize that this is becoming a bit complex, and very much so is outside the scope of the original question.  I don't expect you to look into third party libraries :) I thank you very much for your code suggestions, as they are indeed improvements.

Comment: Actually, I believe to have narrowed this down to the fact that firefox has a problem with document.write().  For each page that has a calendar, I am document.write()-ing some content as the page loads.  I will update my question with information regarding this if I find the solution.